# Maximum distance in a closed static universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, geometry, topology

I'm confused about a detail in cosmology.  Consider a ***static closed*** universe, of the following metric (consider $a$ as a simple constant with units of length) :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2 \big( d\chi^2 + \sin^2 {\chi} \; (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 {\vartheta} \; d\varphi^2) \big).
\end{equation}
Here, the radial coordinate takes values on a bounded domain : $0 \le \chi \le \pi$.  The *proper radial* lenght is defined by this line element ($d\vartheta = d\varphi = 0$) :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
d\ell^2 = a^2 \, d\chi^2.
\end{equation}
Integrating gives trivially $\ell = a \, \chi$.

The ***proper volume*** of the whole space is easily found to be $\mathcal{V} = 2 \pi^2 a^3$, and the area of a sphere of coordinate radius $\chi$ is given by $\mathcal{A}(\chi) = 4 \pi a^2 \sin^2 {\chi}$.  Thus $\mathcal{A}(0) = \mathcal{A}(\pi) = 0$ and $\mathcal{A}_{\text{max}} = \mathcal{A}(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 4 \pi a^2$.

In a closed universe, it is important to not confuse *length* and *distance*.

The question is this :

> *What is the maximal **proper distance** from a given stationary observer in this space : $\mathcal{D}_{\text{max}} = \pi \, a$, or $\mathcal{D}_{\text{max}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \; a$ ?*

I'm confused because of the area behavior, and I believed that the maximal distance is $\mathcal{D}_{\text{max}} = \pi \, a$ and not $\mathcal{D}_{\text{max}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \; a$, despite the fact that $\mathcal{A}(\pi) = 0$.  I'm not sure anymore that it's making sense !  I may have confused *distance* with *length* and I need a confirmation.

If you built a linear structure in that space, its maximal *length* should be $2 \pi \, a$, and the *distance* between both extremities should be 0, right ?  Or is the *lenght* actually $\pi \, a$ ??

Comment: If you're considering only the spatial part of your metric, which happens to be a Riemannian manifold, your question doesn't make sense. In Riemannian manifolds there is no notion of "maximal" distance or length since one can always make ripples around such a path, ending up with a path which is longer than the original one. Now if you mean the maximal distance along a geodesic, it's just a matter of integrating along a great circle of the 3-sphere over the entire range of the parameter.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't make sense.  The *radial distance* element is defined as $d\ell = a \, d\chi$ (equation (1)).  Then the radial distance between observer $\mathcal{O}$ located at $\chi = 0$ and an arbitrary point of coordinate $\chi > 0$ is just $\mathcal{D} = a \, \chi$.  The problem is to define the *fartest* point from $\mathcal{O}$.  Since $0 \le \chi \le \pi$, the maximal distance is apparently $\mathcal{D} = \pi \, a$ (not to be confused with the maximal *length*, which is arbitrary, depending on the curve).  What you described is the *length* of a curve, not a distance.

Comment: The radial distance is a geodesic, so it agrees with my comment above. We're just using different nomenclature. For me (and for geometers I guess), distance and length should mean the same thing.

Comment: I don't agree with your last sentence.  *length* and *distance* are not the same (or why would we have two words for the same thing ?).  However, it is clear that an arbitrary curve (not a geodesic) could have an arbitrary length.  This is obvious.  The word "distance" is usually used to define the *minimal* curve length between two points (i.e. the length of a geodesic, by definition).

Comment: @Mr.K, so dou you agree that the *maximal **distance*** between two points in the closed space is $\mathcal{D}_{\text{max}} = \pi \, a$ ?  And that the *maximal **length*** of a **linear structure** is $\ell_{\text{max}} = 2 \pi \, a$ while the *distance* between both of its extremities is 0 ?

Comment: Synonyms do exist! The general notion of distance as defined in metric spaces does not match with your definition. You're thinking in Euclidean spaces. You can, for example, define $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise. This satisfies all of the distance's axioms and still is not "minimal" in any sense. When you say distance in a context of a manifold, it could be interpreted as the distance along a path, which is the same of a path length. So you should be careful with your nomenclature. Second, that curves could have arbitrary length is not obvious at all and this is only true for...

Comment: ...Riemannian manifolds. Timelike geodesics for example maximize the length! Finally, yes, I do agree that the answer is $\pi a$.

Comment: @Mr.K, I believed that I did defined clearly the distance notion in my question (*proper distance* defined from the metric).  See my sentence above equation (1).  Also, do you agree with the last part of my previous comment ?

Answer (score 2):

The spatial component of the spacetime you describe is a 3-sphere. The largest distance is obtained when $\Delta t=0$ so we can ignore the time direction of the spacetime.

A 3-sphere is natural extension of a 2-sphere. Where a 2-sphere consists of a circle with radius $\sin(\theta)$ for every value of $\theta$, a 3-sphere consists of 2-sphere with radius $\sin(\chi)$ for every value of $\chi$. The largest distance on a 2-sphere is the distance from the north to the south-pole. This corresponds to varying $\theta$ by $\pi$. When the radius is $a$, this gives a distance of $\pi a$.

A similar reasoning lets you travel from one side of the 3-sphere to the other by varying $\chi$ by $\pi$. Here the distance is again $\pi a$.

For the second part of your question. If by maximal length you mean the distance traveled along a space-like path, then there is no maximal length. A path can curl around the 3-sphere and get an infinite length. Even when you demand the path to be straight, i.e., a geodesic, there is no maximal length as the path could travel around the 3-sphere with a small time-like component, thereby forever circling the 3-sphere and obtaining infinite length.

The length of a straight path around the 3-sphere without a time-like component in this coordinate system is $2\pi a$, just as for the 2-sphere.

Comment: Thanks, you then confirm what I was thinking :  the longest *linear* structure in that space would have a ***length*** of $2 \pi \, a$ while both extremities are at a ***distance*** of 0.  So the maximal *distance* (not *length*) is $\pi \, a$, and not $\frac{\pi}{2} \; a$.  The behavior of the spherical area $\mathcal{A}(\chi)$ is weird, though.

Comment: Ok, about the area, I now have a clearer picture from the reduction of a simple 2-sphere.  In this simple case, the equivalent of $\mathcal{A}(\chi)$ would be the circumference of the circle drawn on the surface of the sphere : $\ell(\chi) = 2 \pi \sin{\chi}$, which gives $\ell(0) = \ell(\pi) = 0$ while the limiting circles are on opposite sides of the sphere.  But it is still weird to "visualize" the area for the 3-sphere.